# find a the minimal polynomial ofa 6*6 matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

**Question:**

find minimal polynomial of
$\begin {bmatrix} 1 & -4& 2 & 8& -6&-2 \\
-2&-3&4&10&-6&-2 \\-5&-2&6&9&-3&-3 \\ 4&-1&-3&-2&-1&1 \\ 5&-1&-4&-4&0&1 \\-3&4&0&-6&7&2 \end{bmatrix}$ over $\Bbb Q$.
Hint: Use the fact that the vector space created by $\begin{bmatrix} 2\\1\\4\\-1\\-1\\2 \end{bmatrix}$ is non-trivial.

**Thoughts**
I know how to find it using very long calculation, I guess the hint makes it much shorter, but I don't really get how the hint helps. Could anyone please explain me?
Thanks